# jquery ajax vs browser url

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, get, youtube

I'm trying to use youtube's api to bring back a listing of a user's videos. The request url looks something like:
    http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads
with 'username' being the correct username. This bring back the appropriate url in the browser. However when I try to access that url via jQuery's $.ajax or $.get functions, using something like:

```
$.ajax({   

    //set parameters
    url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads",
    type: "GET",

    //on success
    success: function (data) {
      alert("xml successfully captured\n\n" + data);
    },
    //on error
    error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
      alert(" We're sorry, there seem to be a problem with our connection to youtube.\nYou can access all our videos here: http://www.youtube.com/user/username");
      alert(data);
    }      
  });

  $.get("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

I get an empty document returned. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) here, preventing cross-domain requests...but you can do what you're after with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) in this case (since youtube supports it, as long as JSON data is an option in your code, usually this is *preferred* so I'm hoping this is a solution for you).  Using JSONP looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads?alt=json​',
    dataType: 'jsonp'​​​​,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //entire object here
        //another example
        alert("Feed title: " + data.feed.title.$t);
    }
});​
```

[You can see a working demo here, this grabs the video upload feed for nike](http://jsfiddle.net/2rvKT/).  Just explore the object in the console to see what data you want and grab it :)

Comment: Thanks so much! however, I get an "unexpected token: ILLEGAL" error after the line with "datatype:'jsonp'"...

Comment: Never mind. Some invisible characters lurking in the code :) Thanks again, I appreciate it...